# Not able to search elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am newbie at elasticsearch. Using  elasticsearch 7.8.1 for some custom search for my application.

Here is the sample dataset.
The search that need to happen is something like this:

select * from maintenance_logs
where vinNumber = "xyz"
and organizationId = 1
and dtcCode like %p101%
or subSystem like %p101%
or description like %p101%;

Here is the document stored:

```
GET /maintenance_logs/_search


{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "maintenance_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "41a47230-02d1-11ed-a8f8-813988188fd2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.domain.search.MaintenanceLog",
          "id" : "41a47230-02d1-11ed-a8f8-813988188fd2",
          "maintenanceActivity" : "test103",
          "vinNumber" : "DH34ASD7SDFF84742",
          "organizationId" : 1,
          "partitionYear" : "2022",
          "dtcCode" : "",
          "subSystem" : "",
          "description" : "",
          "odometer" : 91000,
          "statsDate" : "2022-07-13"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "maintenance_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5fac7720-033d-11ed-97e1-a3441dab3d6a",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.search.MaintenanceLog",
          "id" : "5fac7720-033d-11ed-97e1-a3441dab3d6a",
          "maintenanceActivity" : "test103",
          "vinNumber" : "DH34ASD7SDFF84742",
          "organizationId" : 1,
          "partitionYear" : "2022",
          "dtcCode" : "D101",
          "subSystem" : "ac vent",
          "description" : "ac vent replaced",
          "odometer" : 91000,
          "statsDate" : "2022-07-14"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how my Document looks:

```
@Document(indexName = "maintenance_logs", createIndex = true)
public class MaintenanceLog {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String maintenanceActivity;

    private String vinNumber;

    private Integer organizationId;

    private String partitionYear;

    private String dtcCode;

    private String subSystem;

    private String description;

    private Integer odometer;
}
```

Here is my query: The intention is, I have a search bar where lets say I typed p101. Then it should look through all the documents.
do exact match on vin_number and organizatinid, and then whatever matches (partial match eg mysql like query) from any one of these attributes dtcCode or subSystem or maintenanceActivity or description.

```
GET /maintenance_logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        { "term" : { "vinNumber" : "DH34ASD7SDFF84742" } },
        { "term" : { "organizationId" : 1 } }
      ],
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "dtcCode": "p101*" } },
        { "term" : { "subSystem" : "p101*" }}, 
        { "term" : { "maintenanceActivity" : "p101*" }},
        { "term" : { "description" : "p101*" }}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your Elasticsearch query as well ?

Comment: @SagarPatel edited the question and added the query there

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal can you please share your index mapping as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with your query:

One is you are using `term` query instead of `wildcard` query  pattern.
Second is you are trying term query  text type of field for `vinNumber` field.

To resolve this issue, You need to use `wildcard` query instead of `term` query and you need to use `vinNumber.keyword` insted of `vinNumber` (considering you are using multi type field for `vinNumber` as text and keyword both). Please check below query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vinNumber.keyword": "DH34ASD7SDFF84742"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organizationId": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "dtcCode": {
              "value": "d10*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "subSystem": {
              "value": "p101*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "maintenanceActivity": {
              "value": "p101*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "description": {
              "value": "p101*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you need to set `"minimum_should_match": 1` as your query have AND condition with `vinNumber`and `organizationId`.

Comment: thanks Sagar this helps. I had used elasticsearch long time back, need to RTFM once again.

Answer (score 0):

[Term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) are used for exact text matching. If you need to do the partial search you can either use [Wildcard Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), [Regexp Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) or [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

If you are using the default mapping then you need to modify your query as :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "vinNumber.keyword": "DH34ASD7SDFF84742"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "organizationId": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*p101*",
                        "fields": [
                            "dtcCode"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*p101*",
                        "fields": [
                            "subSystem"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*p101*",
                        "fields": [
                            "maintenanceActivity"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*p101*",
                        "fields": [
                            "description"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :
If you need to perform a partial search in such a way that, the text matches from the beginning of the value of the fields `dtcCode`,`subSystem`, etc. then you can simply go with [Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) as well.**